# Make qTip not disappear when hovering the tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I am using qTip: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2 and my current problem is that when I hover the tooltip it disappears (because the target was mouseleave/mouseout).

Is there a way to make it stay visible when I hover the tooltip? I positioned the tooltip so that its right under the target so there are zero empty space between the target and the tooltip.

Comment: Please add some code, especially the jQuery part

Comment: And take a look at the documentation, maybe the hide option will help. http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/hide/

Comment: Check the "hide.target" option [http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/hide/#target](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/hide/#target). By default, the tooltip is hidden when leaving the element .qtip() was called upon.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `fixed`: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/hide/#fixed

You may wish to add a `delay` as well before the tooltip disappears, in case there's some distance between your triggering element and the tooltip.

e.g.

```
$('.moreinfo').qtip({
    content: {
        text: $('<p>This is a tooltip.</p>')
    },
    show: {
        effect: function() { $(this).fadeIn(250); }
    },
    hide: {
        delay: 200,
        fixed: true, // <--- add this
        effect: function() { $(this).fadeOut(250); }
    },
    style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-blue ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-rounded'
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That doesn't help. I have both delay and fixed: ture, but it still disappears when you  mouseover on the tooltip by moving fast

Comment: The [documentation](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/hide/#fixed) clearly states that this is the purpose of `fixed`. If it doesn't work it might be broken in the latest release, I haven't checked.

Answer (score 2):

Use fixed: true as well as leave: false

The problem you might be having is that when you leave the qtip target it is hiding.

Comment: Does "leave: false" go in the "hide" section as well?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, using `fixed:true` alone didn't work for me. Instead, I had to use these configurations (v3.0.3):

```
hide: {
   fixed: true,
   delay:90,
},
position: {
   viewport: $(window)
},
```